# Query runs fine in phpmyadmin but not from script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

```
$query_string = "UPDATE _notifications SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'JTQBPULM3M' ;
UPDATE _notifications SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'KC7KZT2JAT' ;
UPDATE _notifications SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'M6L5T5Z2K0' ;";
$this->db->query($query_string);
```

Query runs fine from phpmyadmin but throws this error if ran from php:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE _notifications SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0
>   WHERE _notificati' at line 2

```
UPDATE _notifications 
SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 
WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'JTQBPULM3M' ; 

UPDATE _notifications 
SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 
WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'KC7KZT2JAT' ; 

UPDATE _notifications 
SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 
WHERE _notifications.notification_id = 'M6L5T5Z2K0' ;
```

#### UPDATE: THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: Could be because the mysql library doesn't allow multiple statements in one query any more, as I recall.

Comment: you could just use an IN to provide multiple values in one query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming my supposition that the problem is that you have multiple statements in the same query, you could try this instead:

```
$query_string = "UPDATE _notifications SET _notifications.notification_flag = 0 
WHERE _notifications.notification_id IN ('JTQBPULM3M', 'KC7KZT2JAT', 'M6L5T5Z2K0')";
$this->db->query($query_string);
```

That would make it a single statement.

I'm assuming that it works in phpMyAdmin because I suspect phpMyAdmin breaks the multiple statements up into separate queries, rather than a single one. (Pure speculation there, mind.)

Answer (score 4):

You're not saying what database wrapper you are using, but many libraries can't do multiple queries. You would have to use the "multi_query" method if provided by the library, or separate them into different ones.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manuals you can do multiple statements like this by setting a parameter when connecting then a lot of messing about. Easier to take the 'script and split and then iterate through if having them altogther is convenient in other ways.

But if you really need to.

[MySql 5.1 Manual Multiple Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)